# WKWebView is not opening .DOCX file

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am not able to open .docx file web url in WKWebView in ios swift. office import 912 error is coming.

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OfficeImportErrorDomain error 912.)

(null)

This error is coming while loading .docx file url in wkwebview

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. You can [edit] your question with additional info, including a [example] to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Did you check this: https://www.errorsolutions.tech/error/office-import-error-domain-912/

Comment: Yes i have checked errorsolutions.tech/error/office-import-error-domain-912 but there is no solution for this. Update office suite in device is mentioned which is not helpful. I need to open .docx file url in WKWEBVIEW.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue! is there any way to fix it?